# Toggle or close find window in atom editor

Tags: find, window, toggle, atom-editor

With the shortkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> I open the find window but there is no `X` or something else to close the window.  The only way for me was to close it by clicking `Find` → `Toggle Find`, because therefore no short key exists.

Comment: The `atom` tag you used for this question is in relation to the XML based syndication format, as this post is about GitHub's Atom Editor I have changed the tag to `atom-editor`. If you are not sure about how to use tags, please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. The "shortkey" is <kbd>ESC</kbd>.